# in opencv for c what function does the exact same thing as Mat::convertTo and cvtColor()

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Im trying to understand opencv's  c function cvSaveImage and pertaining to the 2.4.6 documentation here:

> The function save-image saves the image to the specified file. The image format is
>       chosen based on the filename extension (see (load-image) for the list of extensions).
>       Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (+16u+) in case of `PNG`,`JPEG 2000`, and `TIFF`) single-
>       channel or 3-channel (with `‘BGR’` channel order) images can be saved using 
>       this function. If the format, depth or channel order is different, use 
>       `Mat::convertTo()` , and `cvtColor()` to convert it before saving. Or, use the universal 
>       XML I/O functions to save the image to XML or`YAML` format.

it says "If the format, depth or channel order is different, use `Mat::convertTo()` , and `cvtColor()` to convert it before saving."

what functions would do the same thing in the c interface. if possible please  in include example code in your reply.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm.. I think you are looking for **cvCvtColor**:

> ```
> void cvCvtColor(const CvArr *src, CvArr *dst, int code)
> ```
>
> Converts an image from one color space to another.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html

For example if you have a RGBA image and want to convert it to BGR for saving:

```
cvCvtColor(rgba_src, bgr_dst, CV_RGBA2BGR)
```

In actual code it would be something like:

```
/* Create an IplImage with 3 channels and 8 bits per channel,
   with the same dimensions that rgba_src*/
IplImage *bgr_dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(rgba_src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

cvCvtColor(rgba_src, bgr_dst, CV_RGBA2BGR);
cvReleaseImage(&rgba_src);
```

Something like that.
Remember that you should not release rgba_src if it is a frame from a capture device.

Comment: but what about the c equivelant of Mat::convertTo  the documentation says that cvCvtColor "Converts an image from one color space to another."  and Mat::convertTo "Converts an array to another data type with optional scaling."  can you tell me the c equivelant for Mat::convertTo

Comment: cvCvtColor receives a `cvArr *`, which can be `IplImage*`, `CvMat*` or even `CvSeq*` sometimes. So I think that it should work too. Looking at the docs it doesn't seem to be a direct `Mat::convertTo()` replacement.

(`cvMat` is the "old" version of `Mat`, they are not the same)

Comment: On the other hand, if it doesn't work, you can always do it yourself. You can make your custom "transform from cvMat of kind A to cvMat of kind B".

Comment: Also, you the function `cvConvertScale` May come handy for working with `cvMat *`
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html